# Use the process.env.PORT of node.js in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

I have this code in Node.JS

```
var express = require ('express');
var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listo el puerto ${port}!!`));
```

In this case, I understand it is assigned a system port. But in my Javascript I have the following coding where I try to use Fetch:

```
fetch('https://localhost/')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json));
```

My question is, what do I put here, in my port, to be able to use my answers from my Node.JS in my Javascript file? Since I need the one that randomly assigns me the system ---->.

```
https://localhost/port???
```

Thanks.

Comment: is your client side js hosted by the same node js server?

Comment: @Ringo yes! My client side js hosted by the same node js server

Comment: then you dont need to specify localhost port at all. For example, if your endpoint is `localhost:8080/home`, you can do `fetch("home")`

Comment: But, I dont' know what is the port of my endpoint

Comment: The problem is that only I can put "process.env.PORT" in Node. I don't know what is the port

Comment: your client side js code dont need to know the port #, in my example, `fetch(home)` will hit `localhost:8080/home`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Ringo!!! I could do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ringo said, any fetch to a url like "/path/to/data" will automatically use the current domain:port.

You get this for free!

Specifying the domain and port actually makes your application less resilient, because if you change where you're hosting the application, you'll need to update everything to account for that!

So from your example:

```
fetch('/') // we don't include the https protocol, the localhost domain, or the port.
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json));
```

Comment: Thank you very much @tmeans! I understand!